# How to refer to a figure created by tikzpicture in paper body?

Tags: graphics, floats, cross-referencing

I am relatively new with LaTeX. I created an image by

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
....
\end{figure}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I just don't know how to refer it in paper body by `\ref{compression}`, but this command displays the subsection number instead of the figure number.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please post a minimal working example (or at least provide more detail where you add the `\label` in your code)? Also, you can use backticks or indent blocks with four spaces to format them as code.

Comment: I would suggest you read up on first time LaTeX use, for example via [Wiki LaTeX](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions) which is a good resource, amongst others.

Comment: your code snippet won't compile as is- you've ended the `figure` before ending the `tikzpicture`

Answer (score 9):

without any actual code this one's pretty hard to diagnose, but first and foremost i'd change the code you did include to

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{My Empty Figure}
    \label{compression}
\end{figure}

I'd say look at Figure~\ref{compression}, but there's nothing in it.
```

which should allow you to refer to `compression` in the text as i did.

EDIT:

added the needed caption, as `egreg` pointed out.

Comment: Without a `\caption` command the `\label` won't refer to the figure.

Comment: @egreg whoops!  i suppose *i* should have put together a mwe for myself...

Comment: @egreg i just came across `ArteLaTeX.pdf` and `introtex.pdf` on your website and it made my day.  i don't know any yet, but i'll be starting italian in the fall.  when i can hold a relevant conversation about LaTeX in italian, i will consider my mastery of the language complete lol.

Comment: The first is not mine, but both books try to be accurate both in LaTeX and Italian. :) If you pass by [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com:80/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) we can discuss about them.